# How can I remove strings from text?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a long list of words that I want to remove from my text. For example, I have following text:

blah blah search bla code blah will blah not blah help

Now I want to remove the words, SEARCH, CODE, WILL, NOT, HELP from above string.

How can I do it easily in Java?

I am trying the following code:

```
someString = someString.replaceAll("\\b(search|code|will|not|help)\\b", "");
```

However, I noticed that sometime it doesn't replace couple of words. For example, I was
using word "code" to replace but it didn't replace it (above small example works though). I have huge files that I cannot copy past here :(

Is there any other way to perform the same task? or is there any way to find out what is causing this problem? Any test case?

Comment: if you replace your words with an empty string, that's like removing them, right?

Comment: You seem to know the easy way to do this. I'd say try it and when/if it doesn't work, come back with a concrete problem.

Comment: is there a pattern to when it doesn't work (say case sensitivity) ?

Comment: no, there is case related problems

Comment: try `someString = someString.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(search|code|will|not|help)\\b", "");`

Comment: maybe you can extract a few lines/words, which include a problematic case, or does this case vanish in smaller samples?

Comment: We really need to see a code/input sample that demonstrates the undesired behavior.  At this point, all we can do is offer up wild guesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question correctly.  What's wrong with doing:

```
"blah blah search blah will blah not blah help".replaceAll("(search|will|not|help)", "")
```

Comment: I tried this and sometime, it does not replace some of the words. Is there any way to find out why it does not replace some of the words? Any test case? And isn't it .replaceAll('\\b(SEARCH|WILL|NOT|HELP)\\b', '')

Comment: now you are asking a different question, though.  So, can you post your exact regular expression and examples of those cases when it doesn't work?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky: Your code will translate "knot" to "k" - maybe not the intention.

Comment: no, my intention wasn't to get it exactly right, only to point out a direction.

Comment: What does it mean? knot to k? Dmitry could you please provide some good code that can work? Because in your response you mentioned that it wasn't exactly right.

Comment: the regular expression is correct with \b's (mine didn't have them).  However as you say, there are some cases where it doesn't work.  I think the problem is with the data, not the regular expression.  That is, the regular expression is correct for the data you *think* you have (and how you explained it).  So you need to figure out how your data is different.

Comment: That's a good point.  One example would be if the search word starts or ends with an accented letter like `Ä` or `é`.  By default, Java's `\b` incorrectly recognizes only the ASCII letters, `[A-Za-z]`, as word characters, so it won't match at the beginning of `Àdónde` or the end of `café`.  However, as of Java 7 you can use the [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) modifier to make it behave more correctly.